# How to replace certain characters within a string with ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy

I have a list of files where the last digits of the number all need to be changed in a new column.

Old Column    > New Column

c18154**h1**.jp2 > c18154**20**.jp2 
c18154**h2**.jp2 > c18154**21**.jp2 
c18154**h3**.jp2 > c18154**22**.jp2 
c18154**h4**.jp2 > c18154**23**.jp2 
c18154**h5**.jp2 > c18154**24**.jp2

I tried:

```
!FILE!.replace("h1", "20")
```

Only thing is there are files with 'H1' at the beginning of the name, and those files will be affected with this code. I need to make sure that ONLY the final characters change. So far I can't get the syntax right. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: Remember that ArcPy is simply a module within Python.  There are answers to your question on [Regular Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python
Or are you looking for a Field Calculator script?

Comment: My interpretation of this question is that they are looking for a python field calculator solution.

Comment: He is correct that I am hoping to do this in a script. The link was helpfully, but I was hoping to see in the the context for ArcPy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using field calculator where field2 is the old column:

```
!FIELD2!.replace(!FIELD2![-6:-4],"20")
```

The `!FIELD2![-6:-4]` selects the h1,h2,etc from the end position to be replaced with your text.

Alternatively create if/else statements in the codeblock:

```
def replace(field):
  rep=field[-6:-4]
  if rep == "h1":
    return field.replace(rep,"20")
  elif rep == "h2":
    return field.replace(rep,"21")
  else:
    return field.replace(rep,"000")
```

And: `replace( !FIELD2!)`